# Application of the Spectral Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Suppose $T$ is a compact self-adjoint operator and $f$ is a unit vector such that $\| (T -3)f \| \leq 1/2$. Denote by $p$ the orthogonal projection onto the direct sum of eigenspaces of $T$ with eigenvalue $2 \leq \lambda \leq 4$. I want to show that $$\| p f \| \geq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.$$

I'm unsure of how to consider the norm of $p$ and how to relate it to the eigenvalues. Perhaps $$\| Tf \| = \lambda \| p \circ T f \|?$$

Answer (score 2):

hint: $\Vert(T-3)f\Vert\geq\Vert(T-3)(1-p)f\Vert\geq\Vert(1-p)f\Vert$

Comment: I'm still confused. If we have $\| (1-p)f \| \leq \| (T-3)(1-p)f \| \leq \| (T-3)f \| \leq 1/2$, do we use the $\| (1-p)f \| \leq \frac{1}{2}$ and maybe $\| (1-p)f \| \leq 1 + \| pf \|$?

Comment: then we just use that $f=(1-p)f +pf$ and that $(1-p)f$ and $pf$ are orthogonal to each other

Comment: What? I don't see how that gets the result...

Comment: $\Vert f\Vert^2=\Vert(1-p)f\Vert^2+\Vert pf\Vert^2$